# JS searching function does not search data on every page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, pagination

I am trying to Search records from gridview with pagination, matching with the values entered into textbox, and its working quite fine. Issue is that it only show the records which are at first page , but not search the records from the next pages.

here is my JS. code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Search_Gridview(strKey, strGV) {
        var strGV = '<%= GridView1.ClientID %>';
        var strData = strKey.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        var tblData = document.getElementById(strGV);
        var rowData;

        for (var i = 1; i < tblData.rows.length; i++) {
            rowData = tblData.rows[i].innerHTML;
            var styleDisplay = 'none';
            for (var j = 0; j < strData.length; j++) {
                if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(strData[j]) >= 0)
                    styleDisplay = '';
                else {
                    styleDisplay = 'none';
                    break;
                }
            }
            tblData.rows[i].style.display = styleDisplay;
       }
   }
</script>
```

and my gridview

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Font-Size="20px" onkeyup="Search_Gridview(this, 'gvTest')"></asp:TextBox><br />
<div class="rounded-corners">
  <div style="width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="POS ID" GridLines="Horizontal" BorderColor="#ECF0F1" BorderRadius="15px" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#F2F3F4" RowStyle-Wrap="false"
      HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" RowStyle-BorderColor="#e8e8ec" CssClass="gridviewdesign " RowStyle-CssClass="GV" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_OnSelectedIndexChanged" OnRowCommand="GridView1_OnRowCommand" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_OnRowDeleting" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_OnPageIndexChanging"
      EmptyDataText="No point of sales to display">
      <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridView1" ItemStyle-CssClass="gridviewBody" ButtonType="Image" HeaderText="Actions" DeleteImageUrl="~/assets/global/img/deletee.png" SelectImageUrl="~/assets/global/img/edit.png" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowHeader="True"
          ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="POS ID" HtmlEncode="False" HeaderText="POS ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="POS ID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridView1" ItemStyle-CssClass="gridviewBody" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HtmlEncode="False" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridView1" ItemStyle-CssClass="gridviewBody" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HtmlEncode="False" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridView1" ItemStyle-CssClass="gridviewBody" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HtmlEncode="False" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridView1" ItemStyle-CssClass="gridviewBody" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HtmlEncode="False" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridView1" ItemStyle-CssClass="gridviewBody" />

      </Columns>
      <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-ys" />
    </asp:GridView>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you binding the grid client-side with an object data source?  If you are, there's hope.  Otherwise, JavaScript can only search through what is rendered as HTML on your page.  The current page.

Comment: yes i am 
now how can i correct my JS function?

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1318495.aspx?How+to+use+javascript+to+filter+a+gridview+